# Grouping by month using a date column (DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, group-by

I am trying to create a monthly report for easy review and comparison of runtimes of certain processes.

The raw data needed for that is stored in a Oracle 11g database table, with the runtime being the difference between `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE` which are both formatted as `DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

One dateset is created for each run of a process, so there is a huge number of them stored in that table (several datasets per process per hour).

Now normally this would be pretty straight forward by just using a `GROUP BY` clause, however, I couldn't get it to work in this case. Most likely due to the `DATE` columns being involved with their special format.

Is there any possibility to group the data sets by the month which is stored within the `STARTDATE`column? I already tried using some Oracle date functions  which I found via googling, e.g. `MONTH()` and `EXTRACT()` , but so far I didn't get anywhere with it.

I would greatly appreciate any hints regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
daZza

Comment: Which query did you try? The MONTH function should work fine (but you also need the YEAR)

Comment: I tried `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY MONTH(STARTDATE);` This threw an month is a invalid identifier exception though.

Comment: DATE columns do not have a format in the table. They have an internal representation and then how it is formatted when you query them depend on the settings of your client.

Comment: GROUP BY TRUNC(STARTDATE,'MM') would be a possibility.

Comment: @KimBergHansen Well, they are formatted by the `nls_date_format` setting, which in this case is `DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS`

Comment: @KimBergHansen I'll try that `TRUNC` thingy. Sounds promising

Comment: 1. There is no MONTH function in Oracle SQL. There is a MONTH Operator for the EXTRACT function though. 2. Kim Berg Hansen is right. With nls_date_format you say how you want a date be *shown* when not naming a date format explicitely. It has nothing to do with how dates are *stored* in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a dates month in Oracle you can convert that part to a string and use this:

```
select 
  to_char(startdate, 'yyyymm') as startmonth,
  ....
from ...
group by to_char(startdate, 'yyyymm');
```

Comment: The select of it looks good, excatly what I need. However, the `GROUP BY`clause throws an error: `"not a GROUP BY expression"`

Comment: I suppose you select some other none-aggregated value. Everything you select must either be in GROUP BY or aggregated (MIN, MAX etc.). So `select a, max(b), c from mytable group by a` throws an error, because c is neither in GROUP BY nor being aggregated. Check your query.

Comment: Well, that sucks. If I group by everything I select the grouping doesn't make sense anymore. The only thing I want to group by is the month, while keeping all the other data in its original form (except for being grouped by the month). I'll edit the OP with a data sample, maybe it get clearer then. Give me a minute

Comment: Well nevermind, I looked over the structure again and found a way. Thanks!